# C program working on mac and not on windows

Tags: c

A code to delete the c-th smallest element from an AVL tree using max heaps to find the c-th smallest element is giving the correct output on mac but not returning the correct value on the windows terminal. I attach the piece of code below. Maybe it has to with pointer initialisation. Do let me know. Also the problem is that the value of cth smallest element is coming out to be 0 on windows.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "../helpers/helpers.h"
#include "../prng/mt64.h"
#include "q2.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    // Make sure we have a seed
    if (argc != 3)
    {
        printf("Usage: %s <seed> <array_length>\n", argv[0]);
        exit(1);
    }

    init_genrand64(atoi(argv[1])); // Set the seed for the random number generator

    // Accept the length of the lists from the command line
    int l = atoi(argv[2]);

    // Generate the random array
    unsigned int *arr = generateRandomNumbers(l);
    printf("Random Array: ");
    printArray(arr, l);

    // Part A: Construct the tree and print it inorder after every insertion
    tNode *root = NULL;

    for (int x = 0; x < l; x++)
    {
        root = insertTree(root, arr[x]);
        printf("Inorder: ");
        inorderTree(root);
        printf("\n");
    }

    // Part B: Delete the 4th, 5th and 6th smallest elements and print the tree inorder after each deletion
    int c = 4;
    cNode *centreNode = (cNode *)malloc(sizeof(cNode));
    //  your code here
    int *result = NULL;
    centreNode->maxHeapSize = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < l; i++)
    {
        centreNode->maxHeap = insertMaxHeap(centreNode->maxHeap, &centreNode->maxHeapSize, arr[i]);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    {
        result = CthSmallest(centreNode->maxHeap, centreNode->maxHeapSize, c + i);
        int elementToDelete = *result;
        printf("The %dth smallest element is: %d\n", c + i, elementToDelete);
        root = deleteTree(root, elementToDelete);
        inorderTree(root);
        printf("\n");
        centreNode->maxHeapSize = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < l; i++)
        {
            if (arr[i] == elementToDelete)
            {
                continue;
            }
            centreNode->maxHeap = insertMaxHeap(centreNode->maxHeap, &centreNode->maxHeapSize, arr[i]);
        }
    }
    result = CthSmallest(centreNode->maxHeap, centreNode->maxHeapSize, 7);
    int elementToDelete = *result;
    printf("The %dth smallest element is: %d\n", 6, elementToDelete);
    root = deleteTree(root, elementToDelete);
    inorderTree(root);
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}


int *CthSmallest(int *arr, int n, int c)
{
    // return maxHeap[0];
    int iter = n - c;
    int *size = &n;
    for (int i = 0; i < iter; i++)
    {
        extractMax(arr, size);
    }
    int j = arr[0];
    int *cth = &j;
    return cth;
}

int extractMax(int *arr, int *len)
{
    // return max;
    if (*len <= 0)
    {
        // Handle heap is empty
        return -1;
    }

    int root = arr[0];
    arr[0] = arr[(*len) - 1];
    (*len)--;
    heapifyMax(arr, *len, 0);

    return root;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take a [tour] and see [ask]. Specifically see about [mre].

Comment: Where is the beginning of the first function? Where is the `main` function? Where are your `#include`s? Please [edit] and clarify.

Comment: you do not have **function prototypes** (unless they are in the .h) files. If you do not function return type nad parameters types default to int.

Answer (score 5):

The function `CthSmallest` has undefined behavior:

```
    int j = arr[0];
    int *cth = &j;
    return cth;
```

You return the address of a local variable that becomes invalid as soon as the function returns. Undefined behavior means anything can happen including the expected behavior on one architecture and not on another one as you observe... But it can also fail in various ways, visible or invisible, benign or catastrophic.

It is unclear why this function returns a pointer to `int` instead of an `int`. So an easy fix for you is to change the function return type and return the value directly:

```
int CthSmallest(int *arr, int n, int c)
{
    // return maxHeap[0];
    int iter = n - c;
    int *size = &n;
    for (int i = 0; i < iter; i++)
    {
        extractMax(arr, size);
    }
    return arr[0];
}
```

Comment: Anticipating the next question: _but why does it work on the mac and not on Windows?_

Comment: @Jabberwocky It doesn't work on *either*.  The failure just isn't apparent on Mac.

Comment: @AndrewHenle yes, **I** know that, but does the OP?

Comment: @Jabberwocky I suspect it's burned into the OP's brain by now given the amount of time it must have taken to write the question and the implied time and frustration that motivated the OP.  That's what happened to me for some of my own bug-hunt epics - "Oh, that's what I did wrong?  Well, I won't be making **that** mistake in my code ever again."  The weird thing is how hard bugs like this are to spot in your own code.

Comment: @AndrewHenle so true

Answer (score 1):

```
int *result;
    ...
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    {
        result = CthSmallest(centreNode->maxHeap, centreNode->maxHeapSize, c + i);
        int elementToDelete = *result;
```

It is unclear why you need to return an `int *` from `CthSmallest()` when all you require is an `int`.

The problem is in `CthSmallest()`, which is returning the address of a local variable. This invokes undefined behavior (permissible undefined behavior ranges from ignoring the situation completely with unpredictable results, to having demons fly out of your nose. That should answer why it works on mac but not on Windows, for anything is allowed to happen).

Consider changing the declaration of `CthSmallest()` to:

```
int CthSmallest(int *arr, int n, int c)
```

and changing the code to:

```
#if 0
    int j = arr[0];
    int *cth = &j;
    return cth;
#else 
    return arr[0];
#endif
```

And in the caller, assigning the return value directly to `elementToDelete`.

Comment: This also isnt working, the cth values are either garbage values or 0